# Disable Apache server signature

Tags: php, security

I've just set `expose_php` to `off` via WHM's `Configure PHP and suExec`.

For security purposes I want to additionally hide:

```
Apache ServerSignature/ServerTokens/PHP X-Powered-By
```

I can't find a relevant setting under WHM's `Configure PHP and suExec`.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

## Note:

Following [these](http://hostlater.com/2014/04/hide-server-version-turn-off-signature-2336/) instructions (involving editing Global Configurations), I've found that Server Signature is set to off however it's still outputting.

Comment: I think the only answer you're likely to get here is, don't use WHM.  Edit the Apache configuration directly, or if you don't have rights to do that in your platform, ask the hosting provider to do it.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Apologies. I wasn't aware that novice questions are deemed off-topic. Thanks for the clarification. Hopefully, with enough time, I'll have sufficient experience to partake in the serverfault community.

Comment: It's not really novice questions that are OT, just non-sysadmin.  But hey, do keep coming back and asking more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find .htaccess in website root folder and add:

```
# Disable server signature
ServerSignature Off
```